# How to set cursor position in textBox on button click event using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have two `text boxes` and a button in `windows form app` using `c#`.

when i enter text in `txtbox1` and send that text to `txtbox2` on `button click event`, the cursor also goes to `txtbox2`.

My requirement is when i send data from `textBox1` to `textBox2` on buton click event the cursor should remain in `textBox1`.

Comment: Can you post waht you have tried please?

Comment: Try to put the textBox1.Focus() method at the end of button_Click method code, that will place the cursor into the textBox1.

Comment: thnx  NDraskovic it works :)

Comment: please also tell me that the when i send data to textbox2 it points to the data on the top. I want that the textbox2 must points to the last data send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the buttonClick event just add at the end:

```
textBox1.Focus();
```

[How to: Set Focus in a TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743469.aspx)

Comment: please also tell me that the when i send data to textbox2 it points to the data on the top. I want that the textbox2 must points to the last data send

Answer (score 0):

Any reasons why dont set cursor position manually after the click event?

```
 Cursor.Position = new Point(MyFirstTextbox.Location.X -5, MyFirstTextbox.Location.Y -5);
```

Also Control.Focus() helps you.

Comment: I don't think he means the cursor as the mouse pointer, but as the active control, meaning that he wants the keyboard input to go to textBox1 instead of textBox2

Comment: Yeah, i think too (now...). Lets say his question wasnt specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

On button click write at last:

```
textbox1.focus()
```

`focus` is the method you need to use.